# ¿Cómo establecer un login para los usuarios de impresora?

Tags: c#, python

Estoy realizando un programa de auditoría de impresiones. He hecho el monitor de impresiones en C# usando WMI. Mi problema es cómo forzar al usuario que ingrese sus credenciales para empezar la impresion en red.

He revisado un programa en Python llamado [pykota](http://www.pykota.com/) pero solo funciona para dominios de Linux. ¿Me podrían decir una alternativa para Windows o una librería para C# para control de usuario para impresión?

Comment: como envia el usuario la impresion ? porque entiendo que si la impresora esta en red y el usuario la tiene configurada en la cola de impresiona se tiene el dato de quien o desde donde se envia la imrpesion sin necesidad de ingresar ninguna credencial

Comment: gracias por responder. El proposito del programa es mantener un control de quienes imprime. Las impresoras esta en red el problema que surge es que el ActiveDirectory no hay muchas opciones para los servidores de impresiones y el proposito del login es registrar en una base de datos quien imprime, cuantas paginas y la fecha y hora

Comment: Lo que dice @LeandroTuttini es que lo que necesitas es el nombre de usuario, no su contraseña. Al enviar un mensaje a la impresora, se conoce el nombre de usuario que está enviando el mensaje, entonces puedes capturar ese dato y otros previo a la impresión y registrar tu auditoría.

Comment: el problema es mi jefe, me pide que los usuarios usen sus credenciales por el hecho que no solo uno ocupa la pc,

Comment: Pero aunque varios usuarios usen el mismo PC, cada uno inicia sesión con su usuario y contraseña ¿no?

Comment: Te dejo como coment , los chicos de HP tienen uan solución donde con una tablet, tienen un login para las impresoras que se conecta al Active Directory y cada usuario puede ver las impresiones que ha enviado desde su PC, es algo asi lo que necesitas??

Comment: si esa es la idea de como seria la aplicacion, poder consultar las impresiones que se ha realizado en el active directory, gracias por responder

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es monitorear las impresoras en  red registrando cuando se envia una trabajo a la cola lo puedes lograr por medio de `WMI`.

[Contador de Impresiones](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/ed2ce7c1-9063-4de4-a79e-1c2da092b8b9/contador-de-impresiones?forum=vcses)

[Ayuda con control de Impresiones en c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/7c6a9860-b77d-47ae-bcbe-941295f68081/ayuda-con-control-de-impresiones-en-c?forum=vcses)

Por medio de `Win32_PrintJob` podrias tomar los datos de la impresora, habiendo registrado un job para monitorear de forma remota.

[Monitoring Remote Log Remotely using WMI in C# and .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MonitoringRemoteLogusingWMI11232005020152AM/MonitoringRemoteLogusingWMI.aspx)

El monitor lo deberías registrar para que aplique

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias el monitor de impresion lo hice usando un codigo de [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET] pero mi jefe me pide solicite credenciales para los usuarios por el hecho de no solo uno ocupa la pc. Lo que pensaba era interceptar el proceso de la ip a la hora de imprimir pero no tengo idea de como hacer y cargar la pantalla de login

Comment: Interceptar el proceso de impresion puedes lograrlo ya que puedes monitorear la cola de impresion. El tema es que no vas a poder pausar esta accion, pedir contraseña y luego continuar, mas que nada porque este control de la cola lo realizas desde un servidor no desde la pc de cada usuario

Comment: pues la aplicacion iria en el servidor para monitorea las impresiones, la idea es poder captar la solucitud y pedir credenciales de una base de datos por el hecho que aveces se acaba la tinta de un departamente y se debe realizar la impresion en otro

Comment: Capturar la solicitud puedes hacerlo, ahora frenar la operacion, solicitar credenciales y redireccionar a otra cola de impresion, la verdad lo veo dificil. Esto deberia ser mas bien una capacidad de mas bajo nivel.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Leandro Tuttini, buscare una manera de acceder a bajo nivel

Comment: es que para ir a bajo nivel necesitas del fabricante de la impresora, no vas a poder lograrlo con cualquiera marca que tengas en la red. Como comenta @jasilva hay fabricantes, como ser HP,  que brindan este tipo de soluciones

Comment: gracias por su ayuda, pregunte en otros foros y me dijieron que podria poner un servidor como filtro donde pida credenciales para que envie la peticion al servidor de impresiones gracias de nuevo